# How to compute kerning for each pair of letters?

Tags: c#, c, fonts, kerning, sdl-ttf

[These docs](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_58.html#SEC58) say:

> There's currently no method to retrieve the kerning for a pair of characters from SDL_ttf, However correct kerning will be applied when a string of text is rendered instead of individual glyphs.

However, I want to render all the glyphs to a Texture before hand, and then render them out individually so that I'm not re-creating textures all the time.

Using `TTF_GlyphMetrics` and friends I can get all the information I need except kerning.

I'm no expert on fonts, but [this article](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-ttf) explains kerning fairly well. As I understand it, the kerning only depends on the two adjacent letters, thus to get all the kerning values for an entire font, it would take about 26 letters * 2 (upper/lower) + ~10 symbols, squared = 3844 values = about 15 kB of data, which seems plenty small enough to cache.

So, how can I get the kerning for each pair of letters? It must be possible if they're doing it internally.

Comment: There are probably more pairs than you expect. ASCII has about 100 printable characters, and most fonts have more. Still, on a modern computer, even 1M pairs, whose size fits a byte, doesn't seem a big deal.

Comment: @ugoren: I'm not sure I'd do all the printable characters though, just the ones that are likely to be used. Probably make it configurable though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Kerning.js? There are a number of kerning and letter specific js solutions to adjusting kernings manually so maybe you can look this way?
In Kerning.js, I know you can set specific kernings for pairs of letters, or a whole text. Pairs are particularly interesting because some characters shouldn't have the same kerning together (ex. VA - lower kerning than IA to make the characters looks closer to each other).
I don't know if it helps, hope so!

Comment: Don't think that would have helped me. Where's the kerning data?

Comment: You set the kerning data, I don't know how you can retrieve it if you haven't set it manually. Usually people wish to SET kernings, and not GET the values of default kernings so I don't know. But then again, if you set manually the kerning, you will have the exact value.

Comment: Right, well my question is specifically about getting the data. I'm certainly not counting pixels for 3844+ glyph pairs per font I want to use.